# Postgres 9.4 - Connection refused - when I connect from a remote PC

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a PC, let's call it PC-A (WIndows 8.1), where is running Postgres 9.4. I also hava a java application and it needs to access to the DB,
When I run my Java app on the same PC-A, then from localhost, everything works properly.

When I run my Java application on another PC, let's call it PC-B (WIndows 8.1), therefore it tryes to connect to the DB on PC-A, I get the following error (I translated it in english, below the original message in italian):

```
Postgresql : Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is running with option -i, that enables the TCP/IP connections


org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connessione rifiutata. Controllare 
che il nome dell'host e la porta siano corretti, e che il server (postmaster) sia in esecuzione con l'opzione -i, che abilita le 
connessioni attraverso la rete TCP/IP.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:122)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection.<init>(Jdbc3Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:382)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Database.Registrar.getconnection(Registrar.java:56)
    at Database.Registrar.readParametersFromTable(Registrar.java:844)
    at Managers.FunctionsAndParameters.writeParametersInMyConfiguration(FunctionsAndParameters.java:405)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:59)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:77)
    ... 12 more
```

Looking for similar issues on the web I tried some suggested solutions, without success:

---

I edited the file "pg_hpa.conf" adding:

```
host    all    all    192.168.1.0/24    trust    # it should enable all addresses: 192.168.1.*

host    all    all    192.168.1.6/32    trust    # it should enable the address of PC-A
```

---

I edited the file "pgpostgressql.conf " adding:

```
listen_addresses = '192.168.1.6'    # it should enable the address of PC-A

listen_addresses = '0.0.0.0'        # it should enable all addresses
```

It was also already present:

```
listen_addresses = '*'           # it should enable all addresses
```

---

My Java app on PC-B try to connect to the DB using the following code:

```
String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
Class.forName(driver);
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.6:5432/myDBname, "username" , "password" );
```

Where:

- username e password are the same used when I connect from localhost (and in that case it works)
- 192.168.1.6 is the IP address of PC-A (where is running Postgres)
- 5432 is the port, is the same used when I connect from localhost (and in that case it works)
- myDBname is the DB name

When I run the java app on localhost, then in the same PC-A, I use the same code where instead of "192.168.1.6" there is "127.0.0.1"

---

Using pgAdmin III, I have my database under 1 Server:

- mynameserver (192.168.1.6:5432)

Please Help me!!!

UPDATE:  solved!!! I disabled Windows Firewall and now it works!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may check firewall configuration on both sides, and try to ping PC-A from PC-B to see if there is a connectivity issue between your two hosts.

Note that "Connection refused" is not the same problem as "connection timed out".

And in postgresql.conf you should have only one "listen_addresses" parameter and "*" is the same as "0.0.0.0".

Comment: HI, here some replies:    the ping from PC-A to PC-B and viceversa works properly.     I get Connection refused and not "timed out".   I deleted the "0.0.0.0" and I left the "*".     Sorry, I'm not so expert, what should I check in firewall? do you mean WIndows Firewall?

Comment: Note: I added something regarding pgAdmin III in post... may be it's usefull... Thank you in advance.  Fausto

Comment: HI, I found the problem!  I created a new server in pgAdmin III, using this time the address 192.168.1.6 and not 127.0.0.1 (localhost). Not it works...   If you found my solution usefull please improve my reputation... I need it. Thank you

Comment: Problem NOT solved!! My previous comment was a mistake (an illusion...).   I'm continuing to have the problem...

Comment: UPDATE: This time really solved!!! I disabled Windows Firewall and now it works!!!   If you found my solution usefull please improve my reputation... I need it. Thank you. Fausto

Comment: Sorry for the delay. In the Windows Firewall, you have to accept incoming TCP 5432 traffic on PC-A and outgoing TCP 5432 traffic on PC-B. I don't know Windows Firewall so I can't help you more on this topic.